# COUNTIFS, multiple criteria, including only specific values within date range

Tags: excel, countif

Excel countif - I need to count a list of policies that are within a date range (expired policies) and include specific transaction types.

Originally, I needed to do the countif based on excluding values. Now as the transaction types have grown, it would be more efficient to just include the values I want. Below was the formula based on excluding certain values.

`=COUNTIFS(A1:A4,"<"&DATE(2018,1,15),B1:B4,"<>"&"Can",B1:B4,"<>"&"END")` allows me to exclude values I don't want recorded.

Policies are defined by transaction type: New, Ren, End, Can, REN-1, REN-2 etc...

I only want to count New and Ren within the date formula above however when I edit the above formula to `=COUNTIFS(A1:A4,"<"&DATE(2018,1,15),B1:B4,"New",B1:B4,"REN")` I just get a 0 value. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

You are counting those that are both `New` and `REN` at the same time. Count each individually and add the separate results.